# Using EntityFramework dbContext to get records with count in another table

Tags: c#, dbcontext, entity-framework-4.3.1

I am using EntityFramework 4.3.1 and Database first with dbcontext.

Let's say I have 2 tables:
**Customer**
and
**Order**
with a 1 to many relationship between Customer and Order.

I have two queries that I want to run using EntityFramework to get back specific information for different web pages.

**The first is:**
*Get all Customers who have placed orders since a specific date.*

So, the plain SQL for this query might be something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID IN (
   SELECT CustomerID FROM Order WHERE OrderDate > '01-01-2012'
)
```

I can't figure out how to do this in EntityFramework.

I started with the following code, but can't figure out where to go from here.

```
var customersWithOrdersAfterGivenDate = this._dbContext.Customer
   .Include("Order")
   .Where(c => ??? What do I do here ??? );
```

I tried to do *(c.Order.OrderDate > someDate)*, but this doesn't work because I can't get the OrderDate property from Order since EntityFramework is treating Order as a collection.

**The second problem is:**
*Get the total number of orders for a given collection or Customers*

The plain SQL for this query might look like:

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*)
FROM Order
WHERE CustomerID IN (*someCollectionOfIDs*)
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Again, I have no idea how to do this in EntityFramework. How do I get only the CustomerID and the total count of records for the CustomerID from the Order table? I can't figure out how to do a group by so that it doesn't just return every single order record for each customer.

### ----------------------------------

---

***Update:
Here's my final code after feedback from Eli.***

To get Customers with Orders that were created after a given date:

```
var customerIDs = dbContext.Customer
   .Include("Order")
   .Where(c => c.Order.Any(o => o.DateCreated.CompareTo(startDate) > 0))
   .Select(s => new
      {
         c.CustomerID
      })
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(cust => cust.CustomerID)
   .ToList<int>();
```

To get total count of Orders for each Customer in a given collection of Customers:

```
List<int> customerIDs = GetCustomerIDsToQuery();

var orderTotals = dbContext.Orders
   .Where(o => customerIDs.Contains(o.CustomerID))
   .GroupBy(o => o.CustomerID)
   .Select(o => new
      {
         CustomerID = o.Key,
         TotalOrders = o.Count()
      })
   .AsEnumerable();
```

From the above, I can iterate through the collection and get the values from the anonymous type:

```
foreach(var ot in orderTotals)
{
   var customerID = ot.CustomerID;
   var totalOrders = ot.TotalOrders;
   //Do something with these values...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL also contains a nested collection, so your LINQ will be the same.  Something along the lines of `.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(order => order.OrderDate > someDate));`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed for the first one, and pointed me in the right direction for the second one. I'll add my final result to my OP.

Answer (score 1):

`int noOfRecords = _dbContext.Customer.Count();`

this will return the number of records in a table in Entity framework.

Comment: Thanks, https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx not losing a word about this one.

Comment: usually it's grouped by the id linking the two tables